# Rendering a big file with pystache

Tags: python, mustache

This is what I usually do to render a file with `pystache`:

```
txt = open(filename, 'r').read()
print pystache.render(txt, context).encode('utf-8')
```

("context" is my mapping)

But now I have to render very big templates. Is there a suggested way to do
this, without reading the whole template into memory? Does pystache have internal support for this?

Comment: This is not parsing, but template rendering. Do you mean that you have a really big template?

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there is an [issue](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/issues/108) open on the github page about this. As soon as I get time to follow this I will.

Answer (score 0):

Pystache has no built-in support for template streaming, but it's open source, so if this feature is a priority for your use case, I'd recommend forking the [source](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache) and implementing it yourself.  Honestly, I think it'd be pretty easy to modify the source to optionally take in a template generator which would return lines of text as opposed to taking in the full template text.

*** The easiest solution would probably be to break your large template up into multiple, sub-templates and reference them via partials. ***

You may be interested in template rendering via chunks that mustache.js allows [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: I am not sure this is so easy to implement as you suggest. As far as I know, nothing prevents the delimited pattern to span over several lines. I understand this would be a corner case, but it must be covered.